# Is it possible to delete or edit messages in chat?

Tags: support, chat

Is there any way to edit or delete messages in chat without having to flag them for moderator's attention?

Comment: You can delete/edit your own messages in chat within 2 minutes of posting... after that - the content is effectively locked and you either need a mod to delete/edit or a room owner can move your messages into a separate room.... Why do you ask?

Comment: @JonClements because some times you may need to improve your old chat discussion code and answers, and I don't like the idea of posting things twice with slight modifications.

Comment: The ability to go back and edit/delete old messages is something that's been discussed before and not something that's going to be implemented as the transcripts of the room are publicly available and if people could go back and change messages it could be completely confusing to the flow of conversation (or someone malicious could use it to gaslight people)... There's no harm in posting it in chat again... although if it's a chat related to a question you've answered, then don't forget to consider if the information should be going into a post on the main site rather than just in chat.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for explaining, I see your points now, and I agree with them.

Comment: Cross-site dupe to the effect of what Jon has said: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204506/how-to-repair-or-update-my-messages-in-chat

Comment: @JonClements Care to make that an answer instead of a comment? :-)

Comment: @TylerH I was hoping someone would find a dupe but on MSO and I wouldn't have to... Be my guest though... :)

Comment: but what we can do if we upload a photo that contains sensitive info and we want to delete it?

Comment: Similar question from MSE: [Is it possible to delete a chat conversation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110362/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-chat-conversation)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

Chat messages have a grace period of 2 minutes in which they can be edited or deleted. Once that grace period is over, the chat message has become a permanent contribution to the chat system.

Deletion or edits of those chat messages are then only possible by moderators. [Flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSg12.png) are the most effective way to get the mods attention to such messages.

As an alternative to deletion room owners can *move* a chat message from their room to any other room (except Gallery rooms where you're not an RO or have write access). That "deletes" the message from the room transcript but by following the move message the original can be quickly located.

There does exist the concept of a private room. That is a chatroom that you have to be invited to and is created / configured by a moderator. Private chatrooms are not visible for regular users. A moderator could agree to setup such private room as *Trash/Deletion* room. An RO that is authorized for that private room can then move a message from a public room to the private chat Trash room, effectively *deleting* the message from public viewing. I know of one instance of such room on the Chat.se server. I'm not privy to details if such room exists on Chat.so.

See also [How to repair or update my messages in chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204506/how-to-repair-or-update-my-messages-in-chat)